# Is the colloquial Australian term 'festy' actually a word?

Tags: slang, colloquialisms, is-it-a-word, australian-english

Usage: "I would not like to eat that pie as it looks all **festy** since you dropped it on the ground."

Is the colloquial Australian term '**festy**' actually a word?
Also, is it used elsewhere in the world?

Comment: Think it's a formation from "fester"?

Comment: I'm Australian and don't recognise this word (except as a hypocorism on 'festival'), certainly not in the usage you give. Can you give a reference?

Comment: Perhaps you mean "feisty". Australians sometimes use that word in a similar fashion to what you described. (Only some Australians, mind you, but I have heard it a few times.)

Comment: (Of course, "feisty" doesn't actually mean that.)

Answer (score 1):

The Merriam Webster hasn't heard of it, but the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=festy) lists it with the first two senses as back-constructions of "fester", respectively:
*Bad, disgusting, undesirable, revolting.*
and
*anything that is dirty and/or smelly. It is particularly used to describe people, but may be used to refer to objects or animals.*

As English seems to expand much more than it contracts, it seems that in another decade or so if not less, Webster will list it and then Oxford.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Australian and I've heard the word festy before, it means dirty or disgusting. Sometimes you can call people festy or things.

From the Collins dictionary:

> **[Festy](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/festy)** - dirty, malodorous, very bad

Comment: Hello, Cathryn. To quote tchrist, "We are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers."

Answer (score 0):

It's an Australian word formed by the addition of "y" to the contraction of fester.

Comment: To fester means:*become rotten and offensive to the senses* and *(of a negative feeling or a problem) become worse or more intense, especially through long-term neglect or indifference* If *festy* is a contraction of that word, it sounds like something to avoid at all costs! Ewww. :)

Comment: Hello, Alan. To quote tchrist, "We are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers."